# Good free intro to Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, books

So a friend asked me if I knew of a good Ubuntu tutorial or book. I remembered one from a while ago: the [Ubuntu Pocket Guide](http://www.ubuntupocketguide.com/download_main.html), but it turns out it's from 2008, so it's not really ideal any more.

Are there any others out there that are updated for 10.4 or 10.10?

Comment: there's a dedicated stack for you Gnome-lovin' Ubuntu users. http://www.askubuntu.com that's probably a better place for you to ask. over here's consoles and cold Russian nights.

Comment: I am opposed to the Ubuntu-specific q&a site.

Comment: What specifically is he having issues with or would like to learn about? Gnome and KDE have come a long way and are pretty intuitive now. As long as he knows how to open firefox there shouldn't be a need for a "tutorial".

Comment: @Falmarri - just how to use the system in general. For example, she didn't know how to install software.

Comment: the best tutorial is hands on trial and error, bad as it sounds :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the [Ubuntu Manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

[Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Ubuntu 10.10 Essentials](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ubuntu_10.x_Essentials)